# how to show a presentation on two monitors in LibreOffice?

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice-impress

On the  Microsoft PowerPoint I can show presentation where on first monitor I see notes, on second - Presentation.

How do it in LibreOffice? 
(ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the PresenterConsole Extension. This extension should be bundled with Libreoffice 3.4 and following.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Libreoffice 3.6 (http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.6#Impress), taken from the release notes:

- Correctly detect the external display and put the presenter console on the local display (Michael Meeks)